# Chapter 4 case project

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

Create a view named HighBalance using the the patient number, last name, first name, street, city and zip code for those patients with a balance greater than $1,000. Display the data in the view

Im having trouble creating this SQL command sequence, every time i try to correct it, it gives me an error message saying: Syntax error in CREATE TABLE sequence

```
CREATE Table HighBalance AS
SELECT PatientNum, LastName, FirstNAme, Street, City, ZipCode
FROM Patient
WHERE Balance>1000 ;
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: `CREATE Table` --> `CREATE view`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `FirstNAme` should be `FirstName`?
Perhaps `CREATE TABLE` should be `CREATE VIEW`?

```sql
CREATE VIEW HighBalance AS
SELECT PatientNum, LastName, FirstName, Street, City, ZipCode
FROM Patient
WHERE Balance > 1000;
```

Try this first:

`SELECT * from Patient`

If that works try:

`SELECT * from Patient WHERE Balance > 1000`

If that works try:

```
SELECT PatientNum, LastName, FirstName, Street, City, ZipCode
FROM Patient
WHERE Balance > 1000;
```

Then you will be closer to understanding the problem.